# Searching on the ID field of a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, id

My org has a need to be able to search for documents based on the assigned ID value. When adding files to a library, there are given an internal ID. However, searching on this field yields unpredictable and errant results. For example: I have in my library over 100 documents. When I enter the search term "ID:42" - I get multiple files.  I get ID 42, but also ID 40 and ID 2.

We thought the issue may be that the field is not associated with a managed property, but we're having difficulties in setting that up.

Anyone have any idea why the built-in field returns odd/errant results when searched???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the " listitemid: " field when searching, such as listitemid:11, to accurately search for files with an ID value of 11.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Xyzax - Thanks for the note. This worked.  We are now mapping listItemID to a managed property that is more user-friendly for our employees to remember to use.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I'm glad this is helpful to you, you can click "√" on the left panel of the answer to help more people with the same question as you to quickly retrieve the answer.